# Slim trailing slash route

Tags: php, url-routing, slim

I have this route in a Slim application:

```
$app->get('/fasi/:id/',function ($id) use ($app) {
        $app->render("fasi.html");
});
```

This answers to

```
http://test/fasi/1/
```

but also to

```
http://test/fasi/1
```

Is there any way to force Slim to answer only to the url with the trailing slash (first one) or, to redirect the client adding the trailing slash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make optional the slash and the parameter also, like this:

```
$app->get('/fasi/[:id[/]]',function ($id) use ($app) {
    $app->render("fasi.html");
});
```

This works with:

> http://test/fasi/1

or:

> http://test/fasi/1/

Comment: in Slim 2, using `$app->get('/foo/?',function () use ($app)` actually works, while `$app->get('/foo[/]',function () use ($app)` does not

Comment: i want make it by redirect to domain without slash

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect/rewrite all URLs that end in a / to the non-trailing / equivalent, then you can add this middleware:

```
 use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface as Request;
 use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    $app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
        $uri = $request->getUri();
        $path = $uri->getPath();
        if ($path != '/' && substr($path, -1) == '/') {
            // permanently redirect paths with a trailing slash
            // to their non-trailing counterpart
            $uri = $uri->withPath(substr($path, 0, -1));

            if($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
                return $response->withRedirect((string)$uri, 301);
            }
            else {
                return $next($request->withUri($uri), $response);
            }
        }

        return $next($request, $response);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the trailing slash optional

```
$app->get('/fasi/:id(/)',function ($id) use ($app) {
    $app->render("fasi.html");
});
```

Or add a route which redirects to the route with the trailing slash

```
$app->get('/fasi/:id/',function ($id) use ($app) {
    $app->urlFor('fasi', array('id' => $id));
});

$app->get('/fasi/:id',function ($id) use ($app) {
    $app->urlFor('hello', array('name' => 'Josh'));
})->name('fasi');
```

Or have Apache redirect your request to the same url + a trailing slash, keep in mind that this will redirect ALL urls to add a trailing slash

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The first answer is not what I need: the trailing slash seems to be already optional by default. The third is a bit too much (but can be a solution!). I find very nice the second one, I will try it.

Comment: Not yet, but I will try shortly and I will remember to flag your answer. Thanks

Comment: Syntax in v3 is `/fasi/:id[/]` instead of `/fasi/:id(/)` http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->get('/fasi/{id[0-9]*}{slash:[/]?}',function ($id) use ($app) {
    $app->render("fasi.html");
}
```

try this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @Satit Please provide some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

this is what i did to my slim-framework based app

```
//updated code, we do not want .js .css .png to have trailing slash
    $app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $files = array('.js','.css','.jpeg','.png','.jpg');
    $path = $uri->getPath();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (strpos($uri, $file) == TRUE) {
            return $next($request, $response);          
        }
        else {
            if ($path != '/' && substr($path, -1) != '/') {
            $uri = $uri.'/';
            return $response->withRedirect((string)$uri, 301);
            }
        }
    }
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Comment: The `if ($path != '/' && substr($path, -1) != '/')`-condition in the `foreach`-loop doesn't make sense, as it has no relation to `$file`. Today, we do: https://github.com/middlewares/trailing-slash :)